# DataPoint in chart vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I make spline chart by using array (X,Y)
 I need to find the value of Y when X=3.2 from chart 
 I use this code but do not work
[image: code used]

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you'll see from there that you need to post your code in your question

Comment: Please post your full code and not images of code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.findbyvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2 `Finds the first data point that is equal to the specified value.` and since you don't plot 3.2, no points are equal to it, and it won't do what you want it to. Are you trying to do a linear interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

That function doesn't do what you think it does. Please see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.findbyvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2), specifically the description *Finds the first data point that is equal to the specified value.* Actually, you pass y, not x, into that function so it is the reverse of what you need anyway (plus you need to pass an exact match).

You can write your own function to perform a linear interpolation to find y corresponding to x. This is not spline interpolation. You can look into polynomial least squares fitting if you require greater precision.

```
Private Shared Function Interpolate(xArray As Double(), yArray As Double(), x As Double) As Double
    Dim points = xArray.Select(Of (x As Double, y As Double))(Function(xa, i) (xa, yArray(i))).OrderBy(Function(xy) Math.Abs(xy.x - x)).Take(2)
    Dim m = (points.Last().y - points.First().y) / (points.Last().x - points.First().x)
    Dim b = points.First().y / (points.First().x * m)
    Return m * x + b
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim x(6) As Double
Dim y(6) As Double
x(0) = 1
x(1) = 1.7
x(2) = 2.8
x(3) = 4
x(4) = 2.4
x(5) = 1.5
y(0) = 16
y(1) = 20
y(2) = 40
y(3) = 60
y(4) = 30
y(5) = 20
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
Dim datapoint = Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.FindByValue(3.2) ' is Nothing
Dim yValue = Interpolate(x, y, 3.2)
Label1.Text = yValue.ToString()
' Label1.Text is "54.190" ...
```

Explanation of algorithm: Select x,y pairs in a tuple, order the tuples by |x-x0| (so nearest x's are first), take first two pairs, calculate m,b in y=mx+b, solve y.